# Localization of a Dedekind domain.

Tags: ring-theory, dedekind-domain

I have a question on localizations of Dedekind rings which I am learning about in an undergraduate class. Let $R$ be a Dedekind ring with quotient field $K$, $\mathfrak p$ a nonzero prime ideal in $R$. Let $R_\mathfrak p$ be the localization of $R$ at $\mathfrak p$. 
One assignment question is to show that if $x\in K-R_\mathfrak p$ then $x^{-1}\in R_\mathfrak p$.

If $x=r/s\in K-R_\mathfrak p$ then $r\in R$ and $s\in \mathfrak p$. I don't see how we can deduce $r\notin \mathfrak p$ since we want $s/r\in R_\mathfrak p$.

A hint will be very useful. Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exercise is asking you to prove that $R_\mathfrak{p}$ is a valuation ring (see the first definition in the Wikipedia entry: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_ring#Definitions).

My answer to the following question explains this:

[Discrete valuation ring associated with a prime ideal of a Dedekind domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183467/discrete-valuation-ring-associated-with-a-prime-ideal-of-a-dedekind-domain)

Comment: So the way to solve the question is to show that $R_\mathfrak p$ is a valuation ring through a valuation $v_\mathfrak p$ on $K$? Is $v_\mathfrak p(x)$ the power of $\mathfrak p$ present in the factorization of $xR_\mathfrak p$? Then do we know that $K$ is the quotient field of $R_\mathfrak p$? Sorry for my basic question, I have only started learning this and it seems quite hard. Thank you.

Comment: I can't think of a more direct way. Yes, the valuation is the $\mathfrak{p}$-adic one, meaning that $v_\mathfrak{p}(x)$ is the power of $\mathfrak{p}$ in the fractional ideal $Rx$ (or equivalently $xR_\mathfrak{p}$). If $R$ is a domain with fraction field $K$ and $S\subseteq R\setminus\{0\}$ is a multiplicative set, then there is always a unique $R$-algebra injection $S^{-1}R\hookrightarrow K$, and this realizes $K$ as the quotient field of $S^{-1}R$.

Comment: Do you show that $K$ is the quotient field of $S^{-1}R$ by showing that every element of $K$ lies in $S^{-1}R$? Also in your answer to the linked question, you mention the uniformizer $\pi$ in $R_\mathfrak p$. Is $\pi$ the generator of the unique maximal ideal of $R_\mathfrak p$ and is it a generator of $\mathfrak p$ in $R$ also?

Comment: If every element of $K$ were in $S^{-1}R$ then the map $S^{-1}R\to K$ would be an isomorphism. This is not generally the case (think about $R=\mathbf{Z}$). Every element of $K$ is a quotient of elements of $R$, and in particular, is also a quotient of elements of $S^{-1}R$. Regarding $\pi$, it's a generator of the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{p}R_\mathfrak{p}$, but not necessarily of $\mathfrak{p}$, and there is no reason for $\mathfrak{p}$ to be principal in general.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathfrak{p} = (p)$, with $p$ a rational prime. See what happens in this case, and that should indicate how to proceed in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be helpful for those more comfortable with ideal class groups than valuation rings.

Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain and let $\mathfrak{p}\subset R$ be a non-zero prime ideal.  Let $r,s\in R$ both be non-zero. Let $k_r, k_s$ denote the exponents of $\mathfrak{p}$ in the factorisations of $(r),(s)$ respectively.  Let $k=$min$(k_r,k_s)$.  We know $k=k_r$ or $k=k_s$.  Suppose $k=k_r$.  We will show $\frac sr\in R_{\mathfrak{p}}$.

We have:
\begin{align}
(r)&=&J\mathfrak{p}^k,\\
(s)&=& I\mathfrak{p}^k,\\
\mathfrak{p}&\nsupseteq& J.\,\,\,\,\,\,
\end{align}

Pick $a\in J \,\,\backslash\,\, \mathfrak{p}$. Pick an ideal $K$ such that $JK=(a)$.  Also from the first two equations above, we know  $I$ and $J$ represent the same element of the ideal class group, so we have $IK=(b)$, for some $b\in R$.

Note also $$(s)J\mathfrak{p}^k=(s)(r)=(r)(s)=(r)I\mathfrak{p}^k,$$
so $$(s)J=(r)I.$$

Putting this all together:$$(sa)=(s)(a)=(s)JK=(r)IK=(r)(b)=(rb),$$
so $sa=rbu$ for some unit $u\in R$.  We selected $a\notin \mathfrak{p}$, so we may conclude: $$\frac sr=\frac{bu}a\in R_{\mathfrak{p}}.$$